# How do I get ubuntu 16.04 ARM64 iso get working on Pi3B

Tags: pi-3

I downloaded ubuntu 16.04 arm64 iso image , and used Etcher to flash on to SD card.
But my Pi3 B does not boot ?? anyone faced this issue and how to fix.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the generic ARM64 ISO.
Use the Raspberry Pi disk image: https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi

There is no 64-bit Raspberry Pi version of Ubuntu 16.04, only a 32-bit Raspberry Pi 2 version:
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/xenial/release

If you *really* want to use Ubuntu 16.04 (why?), you can try this guide: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi#Booting_generic_arm64_ISO_images

Keep in mind that the Raspberry Pi is different from your normal computer. It doesn't have a BIOS, you need device trees etc., so "just" booting an ISO isn't easy. You also need Broadcom's proprietary BLOB firmwares for the GPU, bootcode.bin and some custom start files, etc. Also keep in mind that the Raspberry Pi images use a slightly different version of the Linux kernel than the one used by generic ARM64 Ubuntu images.

Comment: Thanks, but I am specifically looking for ubuntu 16.04 ARM 64   like :   ubuntu-16.04-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi.img . I am unable to locate this image ??

Comment: @user118802 There is no 64-bit Raspberry Pi version of Ubuntu 16.04. See the update I made to my answer. Why do you need Ubuntu 16.04 anyway?

Comment: Thanks, The reason to want to use 16.04 is that it has support for very old lxc version 2.0.11, which is what i am looking for